# Toast Message in a ContentResolver

Tags: android, android-cursor, onactivityresult, android-toast

I want to Pick a Contact and display the number as Toast Message with onActivityResult.
My Problem is after i've picked a Contact and want to Display the number my programm is Crashing.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri contactUri = data.getData();

            String[] projection = { Phone.NUMBER };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri,
                    projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();


            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(column);

            // Should Display the number as Toast
            Toast.makeText(null, number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

and the StackTrace

```
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222): Process: com.alphabuddy.test, PID: 9222
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure   delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content:  (has extras) }} to activity {com.alphabuddy.test/com.alphabuddy.test.Satabase}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at com.alphabuddy.test.Satabase.onActivityResult(Satabase.java:72)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java)
05-20 16:48:31.990: E/AndroidRuntime(9222):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: if you dont post a stack trace how do you expect use to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Toast.makeText(null, number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

use

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```